# Split rows based on defined values for column from csv file

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl, flat-file

I have data as below into csv file and I want to pick certain data from it using ssis technology

I need only those rows from ID column `23145`, `876459`, `1022`

```
+--------+------+-----------+
|   ID   | Name |  Address  |
+--------+------+-----------+
|   1022 | XYZ  | Texas     |
|   2347 | zzz  | Virginia  |
|  23145 | TTT  | New York  |
|  45673 | ZWT  | Maryland  |
|   9870 | RET  | Florida   |
| 876459 | TERW | Oklahoma  |
| 980456 | YUIE | Georgia   |
+--------+------+-----------+
```

Result expected

```
+------+----------+
| Name | Address  |
+------+----------+
| TTT  | New York |
| TERW | Oklahoma |
| XYZ  | Texas    |
+------+----------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use a conditional split component within a data flow task to filter rows based on ID using a similar expression:

```
[ID] == 23145 || [ID] == 876459 || [ID] == 1022
```

For more information about SSIS conditional split you can refer to the following article:

- [SSIS Conditional Split Transformation overview](https://www.sqlshack.com/ssis-conditional-split-transform-overview/)

---

### Update 1 - Filtering using two columns

Try to use `&&` (and) and `||` (or) operators within your expression:

```
([Name] == "TTT" && [Address] == "New York") || ([Name] == "TERW" && [Address] == "Oklahoma") || ([Name] == "XYZ" && [Address] == "Texas")
```

Comment: Hadi - Sorry , I just realized that I just want two columns without Id column, I corrected my result on my question.